# can't generating a new JTable

Tags: java, swing

I have a window with a Jtable, tree buttons and a textview. I would like that when I fill something in the textview and then I click on a button, I generate a JTable with the results of a query. I begin the program with a sample table of a query established. My problem is that when I click a button, execute the query but the JTable original don't disappears and not appears the new JTable with the new data.
Could you help me please? Many thanks and sorry for my english!
The button code:

```
 if (arg0.getActionCommand().contentEquals("Buscar Anteriores")){
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        BaseDeDatos baseAnt = new BaseDeDatos();
                        ConversorResultSetADefaultTableModel conversar2 = new ConversorResultSetADefaultTableModel();
                        ConversorResultSetADefaultTableModel conversorAnt = new ConversorResultSetADefaultTableModel();
                        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
                        modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
                        UI initAnt = new UI();
                        baseAnt.estableceConexion();

                        //initAnt.creaYMuestraVentana();

                        ResultSet rsAnt = baseAnt.dameListaPersonas();
                        conversar2.rellena(rsAnt, modelo);
                        initAnt.tomaDatos(modelo);

                    }
```

Fill the data in model

```
public static void rellena(ResultSet rs, DefaultTableModel modelo)
    {
        configuraColumnas(rs, modelo);
        vaciaFilasModelo(modelo);
        anhadeFilasDeDatos(rs, modelo);
    }

    /**
     * Añade al DefaultTableModel las filas correspondientes al ResultSet.
     * @param rs El resultado de la consulta a base de datos
     * @param modelo El DefaultTableModel que queremos rellenar.
     */
    private static void anhadeFilasDeDatos(ResultSet rs,
            DefaultTableModel modelo)
    {
        int numeroFila = 0;
        System.out.println("fila cogeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
        if (rs == null) {
         System.out.println("NULLLO");
        }

        try
        {

        //   Para cada registro de resultado en la consulta 
            while (rs.next())
            {
                // Se crea y rellena la fila para el modelo de la tabla.
                Object[] datosFila = new Object[modelo.getColumnCount()];
                for (int i = 0; i < modelo.getColumnCount(); i++)
                    datosFila[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                modelo.addRow(datosFila);
                numeroFila++;
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    /**
     * Borra todas las filas del modelo.
     * @param modelo El modelo para la tabla.
     */
    private static void vaciaFilasModelo(final DefaultTableModel modelo)
    {
        // La llamada se hace in un invokeAndWait para que se ejecute en el
        // hilo de refresco de ventanas y evitar que salten excepciones
        // durante dicho refresco.
        try
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
            {

                public void run()
                {
                    while (modelo.getRowCount() > 0)
                        modelo.removeRow(0);
                }

            });
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Pone en el modelo para la tabla tantas columnas como tiene el resultado
     * de la consulta a base de datos.
     * @param rs Resultado de consulta a base de datos.
     * @param modelo Modelo de la tabla.
     */
    public static void configuraColumnas2(final ResultSet rs,
            final DefaultTableModel modelo)
    {

            System.out.println("CONNNNNNNNFIFFFFFGURAAAAAAAAANDDDDDDDDOOOOOOOOOOOO COLLLUUUUUUUMMMMMNAS");
            // Se hace en un invokeAndWait para que este código se ejecute
            // en el hilo de refresco de ventanas, evitando que salten
            // excepciones.

                        // Se obtiene los metadatos de la consulta. Con ellos
                        // podemos obtener el número de columnas y el nombre
                        // de las mismas.
                        ResultSetMetaData metaDatos;
                        try {
                            metaDatos = rs.getMetaData();
                            int numeroColumnas;
                            numeroColumnas = metaDatos.getColumnCount();
                            Object[] etiquetas = new Object[numeroColumnas];
                            for (int i = 0; i < numeroColumnas; i++)
                            {
                                etiquetas[i] = metaDatos.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
                                System.out.println("etiquetas son .... " + etiquetas[i]);

                            }

                            modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(etiquetas);

                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 

                }

    public static void configuraColumnas(final ResultSet rs,
            final DefaultTableModel modelo)
    {
        try
        {
            // Se hace en un invokeAndWait para que este código se ejecute
            // en el hilo de refresco de ventanas, evitando que salten
            // excepciones.
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
            {

                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {

                        // Se obtiene los metadatos de la consulta. Con ellos
                        // podemos obtener el número de columnas y el nombre
                        // de las mismas.
                        ResultSetMetaData metaDatos = rs.getMetaData();

                        // Se obtiene el numero de columnas.
                        int numeroColumnas = metaDatos.getColumnCount();

                        // Se obtienen las etiquetas para cada columna
                        Object[] etiquetas = new Object[numeroColumnas];
                        for (int i = 0; i < numeroColumnas; i++)
                        {
                            etiquetas[i] = metaDatos.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
                        }

                        // Se meten las etiquetas en el modelo. El numero
                        // de columnas se ajusta automáticamente.
                        modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(etiquetas);
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: beware: you are likely (can't be entirely sure, as you don't show the complete code, but looks like you are starting a thread that's accessing the model off the EDT) violating Swing's single Thread rule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set the `TableModel`.

In the `Runnable.run()` you create a new `DefaultTableModel` and you assign it to the local variable `modelo`.

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
```

But there is no call to set the new table model instance to the JTable that you have. If the `JTable` has no reference to this model how could it listen to changes?

You must do something like this:

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
jTable.setModel(modelo);
```

---

The second line of this code is unnecessary

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
modelo = new DefaultTableModel(); // remove this line
```